# Legacy MBR - what's between offsets 424 and 440?

Tags: uefi, guid-partition-table

According to section 5.2.1 - "Legacy Master Boot Record (MBR)" - of UEFI Specification Version 2.6 (the most recent one available on UEFI official website) a legacy MBR starts with a BootCode which is 424 bytes long. It's followed by a UniqueMBRDiskSignature, but it starts at offset 440, not 424. The obvious question is: what's between offsets 424 and 440? The missing 16 bytes are not mentioned at all.

Comment: The size of bootstrap code area is 440 bytes; There might be different boot codes that's why the size is a bit different, some uses all 440 bytes but some does not. UEFI doesn't use boot code at all.

Comment: I wonder - maybe they meant 440 instead of 424 and it's just a mistake? Every other byte is precisely described in the document (even the ones that are currently not used and are only reserved for future use).